# How do I close a pop-up window & return a view model to the previous view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC5 application I am opening a pop-up window like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openNewWindow(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("/Index/PopUp", "New Window", "height=700,width=500");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

> In the pop-up I made a selection on some data & want a to return a view model to the previous view - is this possible?

I'm starting to think using a pop-up might not be the best idea but I'd be interested to hear of any possible solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a global reference for the opened `window`, use `.close()` to close the opened `window`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.popup = void 0;
    function openNewWindow(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.popup = window.open("/Index/PopUp", "New Window", "height=700,width=500");
        return false;
    }
    // do stuff after call to `openNewWindow`
    // close `window.popup`
    // window.popup.close();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible (in the way you wanna do it), you need to post the data to the server, and load the initial view again to refresh it's content, why are you not using ajax calls to web services (rest end-points) to handle the datamodels, and you don't need window.open, you can use jquery modal dialog instead?